# Default Value for Select with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shandylion/2r3z1uma/

I need to display a list of objects as a list of dropdowns, where changing a dropdown changes the corresponding element in the list.  Ideally, each dropdown should default to that element.

So, with the following data:

```
$scope.allPeople = [{"name":"Ann", "Age":10},
                    {"name":"Barb", "Age":20},
                    {"name":"Carl", "Age":30}];
$scope.selectedPeople = [{"name":"Ann", "Age":10},
                         {"name":"Carl", "Age":30}];
```

and the following HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="selectedPerson in selectedPeople">
  <select ng-options="person as person.name for person in allPeople"
         ng-model="selectedPeople[$index]"
         name="select-{{$index}}" id="select-{{$index}}"></select>
</div>
```

there should be two dropdowns, with the first defaulting to "Ann" and the second to "Carl".

I've tried using `ng-selected`, but that only seems to work with `<option>` tags, not inside a `<select>`.  Other Stack Overflow posts suggest we should always use `ng-options` and never an `<option>` with an `ng-repeat`, so I'm stuck as to how to get this to default to the appropriate value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [sample plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cZk6MSGYVUR90E841p2N?p=preview), which has a working solution as well as the faulty one described below.

The pitfall with dropdowns is that when you want to preselect a value from a list of options, the selected model should be a reference pointing to the same object from the bound list. Say you have:

```
var list = [{ id: 1, value: 'first'}];
var model = { id: 1, value: 'first' };
<select ng-options="item.value for item in list" ng-model="model"></select>
```

This will **not** preselect the dropdown, because `list[0]` and `model` are not the same object, although they look alike. If you set `ng-model` to `list[0]` it should be preselected just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `person.name for person in allPeople`, the selected option returns `person.name` as value. You're presetting your `$scope.selectedPeople` array's values as objects, which does not match with what your select list will return, and hence your initial values are not set properly.
If you want to have `person.name` as the value of each option, you should change your `$scope.selectedPeople` to this:

```
$scope.selectedPeople = ["Ann", "Carl"];
```

On the other hand if you want to return `person` as the value of each option, change your ng-options expression to `person as person.name for person in allPeople`, which means you return `person` and show it as `person.name` for each `person` in `$scope.allPeople`.

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for your suggestion, but neither of these options seems to work for me.  I will add a jsFiddle example soon to augment the question.

Comment: Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bt3urpg4/) .
The adjustments were made based on @Boyomarinov's answer, so you really should choose him as the chosen answer :)